# Powershell pull a domains from a list of urls

Tags: powershell

I have a list of urls in a text file

I want to pull just the domain out.

Running the following:

```
(Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt") | ForEach-Object {$url = New-Object System.uri $_;$url.Host} > d:\test.txt
```

It generates this error:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."
```

And the text file is just that domain (and just the domain, not the path following the domain) over and over again.

Any thoughts on where I'm monkeying this up?

Sample File:

```
lrp.mxptint.net
lrpush.apxlv.com
lsa.measure.ly
lsa.measure.ly\lsa.js?1449665894174&meta_keywords=Life%2C%20lifestyle%2C%20fashi‌​on%2C%20beauty%2C%20Vancouver%2C%20British%20Columbia%2C%20family%2C%20relationsh‌​ips%2C%20home%2C%20blogs%2C%20news%2C%20jobs%2C%20content%2C%20pets%2C%20food%2C%‌​20beauty&autofire=true&windowlocation=www.vancouversun.com\life\diversions lsa.measure.ly\lsa.js?1449665960913&meta_keywords=horoscopes&autofire=true&windo‌​wlocation=news.nationalpost.com\category\life
```

Comment: can you share a sample of what is contained in `test.txt`?

Comment: Sure, I had it in my original post it it wouldn't let me post it.

lrp.mxptint.net
lrpush.apxlv.com
lsa.measure.ly
lsa.measure.ly\lsa.js?1449665894174&meta_keywords=Life%2C%20lifestyle%2C%20fashion%2C%20beauty%2C%20Vancouver%2C%20British%20Columbia%2C%20family%2C%20relationships%2C%20home%2C%20blogs%2C%20news%2C%20jobs%2C%20content%2C%20pets%2C%20food%2C%20beauty&autofire=true&windowlocation=www.vancouversun.com\life\diversions
lsa.measure.ly\lsa.js?1449665960913&meta_keywords=horoscopes&autofire=true&windowlocation=news.nationalpost.com\category\life

Comment: If it were me, I'd look up "regex domain from url" and convert an example to powershell's regex syntax

Comment: That last URL is not valid in that all the slashes are backwards. Is it that way in your text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, djs gave an answer stating why what you are doing doesn't work, and Buxmaniak gave a good functional answer on how to do it via URI object and RegEx both. I just wanted to post a simplified version that works for the sample that you provided...

```
Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" | %{[URI]"http://$_"} | Select -Expand Host | Set-Content D:\Test.txt
```

That will add the http:// to the beginning of the string, and cast it as a URI. Then it expands the Host property from each URI object, and saves it all to the file you specified.

Comment: well, hey, the OP asked what was wrong, not for a working solution... :p

Answer (score 3):

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax), a URI starts with a scheme (usually the protocol, such as `http`). As such, the [.Net URI constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=vs.110).aspx) expects the string to start with the protocol. For example, `http://www.example.com`. You will get the `Invalid URI` exception if you pass in `www.example.com`, etc.

Comment: So if I add http:// to the start of every line (strip it out first and then add it back), it should be good to go?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on [System.Uri] ...

```
@((Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\text.txt") | ForEach-Object { if ($_.Trim()) { (New-Object -TypeName System.Uri ("http://{0}" -f (($_.Trim()) -replace "\\", "/"))).Host } } ) | Sort-Object -Unique
```

... or if you like RegEx, you should try this ...

```
@((Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\text.txt") | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match "^([\w\.-]*)") { $matches[1] } }) | Sort-Object -Unique
```

In both cases the result is ...

```
lrp.mxptint.net
lrpush.apxlv.com
lsa.measure.ly
```

Comment: Even easier for the URI code: `GC $File | %{[URI]"http://$($_ -replace "^.*//")"} | Select -Expand Host` (I stripped and re-added the 'http://' because his sample does not have that so this works for both your sample and the OP's). And simpler RegEx solution: `GC $File -Replace "^.*?://([^/]*)(/.*)$", '$1'`

Comment: It worked for your original example. It doesn't work against the OP's example. This will do it: `GC $File -replace "^(?:.*?:\/\/)?(.+?)(\\.*$|\/.*$|$)", '$1'`

Comment: Get-Content doesn’t know a parameter replace.  `(GC $File) -replace ...` would possibly working.